# Django Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'ModelsChoiceField'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import Form
from .models import LedON, Device

class DownlinkForm(forms.Form):
    Device_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Device.objects.all() )
    Time_intervall = forms.IntegerField()
    Led1 = forms.ModelsChoiceField(queryset = LedON.objects.all() )
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from app.models import *
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField

class LedON(models.Model):
    Ledon = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'ledon'

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.Ledon)

class DevEUIModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.DevEUI

class LedonModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.Ledon
```

The Device object is working and show me the `ModelChoiceField`.
But I don't understand why the Ledon isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your actual code, you have a typo, it's `ModelChoiceField`, but you had `ModelsChoiceField`.